# How to configure Visual Studio With Gitlab - Linux

Tags: visual-studio, gitlab

I want configure visual studio code to push change's project to GitLab.
I'm using Linux. Every time that I try do push, show this message to me:

```
Username for 'https://gitlab.com':
```

I generated ssh key and put in the GitLab user setting.

Git init, add. and commit works fine.

Answer (score 1):

> I generated ssh key and put in the gitlab user setting.

If Visual Studio is asking about https, that means the remote URL associated with your local Git repo is *not* an ssh one.

---

In command-line, go to your repo root folder, and type:

```
git remote origin set-url git@gitlab.com:<yourAccount>/<yourRepo.git>
```

That will help Visual Studio Code pick the right URL (the one for which you registered your credentials through your public SSH key)

---

OR: you might want to keep your current https URL, but cache your GitLab username/password (since you don't want to have to enter them every time).
See "[Use Git Credential Managers to Authenticate to Visual Studio Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/set-up-credential-managers)" (it should apply to Visual Studio Code as well, and works on Windows or on Linux)